# Import multiple txt files fast, handle empty rows and include filename in table in R

Tags: r

**I want to calculate the average likes and shares per user.** Currently I'm trying to do this by importing all data to R and then calculate - if you have other approaches I'm happy to try them.

I have 40,000 txt files. Each txt file represents a user, including every post, its likes and its shares, e.g.

```
file        Text               likes      shares
user1.txt   exampletext 1      13         5
            exampletext 2      1          0
user2.txt   othertext1         192        0
            othertext2         11         18
            othertext2         77         5
...
```

- Column separator is a ";", each new data entry/row is closed by a "/n".
- Some txt files are empty
- I do not need the text, only the likes and shares - if that helps

I tried two ways (both from stackoverflow, thanks so far!):

```
setwd('path')
filelist <- list.files()
res <- rbindlist(lapply(dir(pattern = "\\.txt"), fread))
```

-> fast, but it cannot handle empty rows and it does label the row entries with the file name. If I don't have the file name, I cannot get the mean likes and shares per user.

```
setwd('path')
filelist <- list.files()

Results <-  NULL
for (i in filelist){
  i.file <- tryCatch(fread(i,colClasses="NULL", nThread = 4), error=function(e) e)

  if(!class(i.file)[1]=="data.table"){
    i.file <- data.table(cbind(txt.file=i,is.empty="YES",
                               message=i.file$message))
  } else if(nrow(i.file)==0){
    i.file <- data.table(cbind(txt.file=i,is.empty="YES",
                               message=NA))
  } else {
    i.file[,txt.file:=i]
    i.file[,is.empty:="No"]
  }
  Results <- rbind(Results,i.file,fill=TRUE)
  rm(i.file);gc()
}
```

-> works but is very slow and would take weeks to finish.

Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: I think we need to backtrack here and ask the question of why you are using 40K text files to store your data, when in fact something like a database would probably be a much better thing to use?  So...why are you writing so many text files?

Comment: Does every .txt file have three columns `Text`, `likes`, and `shares`?

Comment: This is the way I got the data. I have no experience concerning mysql and would want to avoid using a program that is new to me.

Comment: @ChrissPaul: yes, except the empty ones.